# Movie about underground creatures that attack during eclipses

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie recently, on the Sci-Fi Channel in 2016. In the movie, scientists drilling in the ground release creatures that attack during every eclipse. One of the characters is a man who takes his son and heads to his uncle's bunker.

Comment: It sounds a little like [Pitch Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_Black_(film)), although I don’t think the creatures in that are released by drilling, nor does anyone have a bunker-owning family member.

Comment: [Transmission](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2100673/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt) has aliens that attack during an eclipse.

Comment: Can you remember the date it aired?

Comment: There was a part in Pitch Black where the survivors came across an abandoned well / drill site which may have initially disturbed the underground creatures, though.

Comment: If you have even a vague recollection of the movie's name, and it happened to be a movie made specifically for the Sci Fi channel between 2001 and 2009, then it might be worth looking through [Wikipedia's List of Sci Fi Pictures original films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Sci_Fi_Pictures_original_films) - one of those names might jog your memory. The description of the list says _"This is the list of films produced and/or televised under the Sci Fi Pictures label of the cable television channel the Sci Fi Channel from 2001 to 2009 when it was renamed Syfy."_

Answer (score 9):

["Day of Reckoning" (2016)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5742568/) is the name of the movie you're looking for!

[image: Cover image of "Day of Reckoning"]

You can find a description in [this review](http://culturecrypt.com/movie-reviews/day-of-reckoning-2016):

> During an eclipse, subterranean creatures unexpectedly rise from underground and swarm the globe attempting to exterminate mankind. Militaries of the world eventually battle back the monsters during the daylong event, which comes to be known as ‘The Day of Reckoning.’
>
> 15 Years Later – With the world bracing for another eclipse and possible creature attack, David Shepherd picks up his teenage son Tyler from his ex-wife Laura for weekend visitation. When word later breaks that an attack is imminent, Tyler sneaks away to a skate park to make sure his girlfriend Maddie is safe.

....

> While arguing over their next course of action and who should drive, a creature kills Milton. David, Laura, Tyler, and Maddie make it to another vehicle and head to the desert outside Barstow, where David’s Uncle Ted has a fortified bunker.

Comment: Can you provide any more details about the film which suggest they are the same? Some people may find this question but be unsure if they're looking for the same film, adding details can be beneficial

Comment: Wow looks like a total ripoff of Pitch Black

Comment: @Paul More like a bad cross between Buffy S7, Spiderwick and some Zombie apocalypse movie, with a splash of family sitcom thrown in.  I mean salt? Really? And no one figured it out last time?